# RNN LSTM overfitting

Tags: deep-learning, overfitting, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to build a dynamic RNN network for 2-class classification, and I just can't get rid of the overfitting. I have 5500 samples of class A, and 8000 for class B (total 13500). From that I take 70% for training, 15% validation, and 15% for test.
*I can get more data but I'm not sure this is what's causing the overfitting.*

Here are the graphs:

[image: rnn graphs]
**Red: train**
**Blue: validation**

The data is reddit posts (tokenized by `nltk.word_tokenize()`), and the labels are the OP's ages. Since the posts are of different lengths, I'm using dynamic RNN. Here are the network parameters:

BATCH_SIZE = 128
MIN_POST_LENGTH = 10 #in tokens
MAX_POST_LENGTH = 50 #in tokens
LEARNING_RATE = 0.1
NUM_OF_LAYERS = 3
LAYER_SIZE = 64 #features
TRAIN_DROPOUT = 0.5
Optimizer: GradientDescentOptimizer
Loss function: reduce_mean

For building the vocabulary I sort the words by their popularity, use the rank as index, <strike>and then normalize to 0 mean and 1 std</strike>. I don't take all the words though, only top X, because most words' frequency is very low (I tried different X's...).

What should I change in order to overcome this overfitting? I tried playing with the batch size, learning rate, changing the optimizer... Nothing helped.

Comment: Why are you using this ranking scheme for the words instead of an embedding? I’ve never seen someone featureize words this way, but lots of people have had success using embedding strategies; see for example [tag:word2vec].

Comment: @Sycorax - I've seen it many times... For example: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/dynamic_rnn.py

Comment: @Sycorax - I will do embedding if necessary. But if something easier works then why not... I just didn't find any claim that embedding representation can reduce overfitting

Comment: Since the model loss and accuracy are basically unchanged for many epochs, before catastrophically overfitting, I would look into alternative ways to represent the data to the model. I don't see how the code you linked has any relevance to this problem, since the sequences in that code snippet do not represent natural language, but are just distinguishing between linear and random sequences of integers.

Comment: @Sycorax - You're right, [this is the correct link](https://github.com/roatienza/Deep-Learning-Experiments/blob/master/Experiments/Tensorflow/RNN/rnn_words.py). Please see `build_dataset()` (I do the same + normalization)

Comment: Regarding underfitting, I understand your point... So I'll look into word embedding then... Thank you

Comment: The strategy they use here is just a 1-hot encoding where the most frequent words have lower indices assigned to them. This is different from your scheme because you apply 0-mean and 1-sd scaling to the data; the code that you linked uses the 1-hot binary vectors directly as inputs.

Comment: I see. So if I disable the normalization, and let my age labels vector be this 1-hot representation, then my approach would be acceptable? I will try word embedding nonetheless but I'm just interested to know.